# Auto response to incoming call with SMS

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to auto respond to incoming call with an SMS?

For example if a user is on a metting and want to set is phone state to busy, and automaticlly  send reponse SMS saying "I am busy, call you later".

I saw that blocking incoming phones is impossible, but here i want the call to come and simply send reply SMS automaticlly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible,it can be done by creating a broadcast listener and sms Manager,that is whenever the app is turned to **do not disturb** mode,you can register any incoming phone number in the app and can send an automated sms reply to  the number as soon as possible. and as the matter of fact there's already an app present in the [app store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.mm)